# How can I make an if else function in custom XPath in the graphical mapping node in IIB?

Tags: xpath

In the graphical mapping node in IIB (IBM Integration Bus) I need to assign a text value to an element of the response message. I want to do this with the Built-in XPath transforms in the mapping node.

The text value is conditional based on whether the element exists or is empty in the request message.

What is going wrong in below XPath code?

`if (fn:exists($BookName) and (fn:nilled( $BookName) = false)) then 'text1' else 'text2'`

Comment: What kind of error message do you get ? What's the ouput with :  `if (fn:exists($BookName) and (fn:nilled( $BookName) = false)) then (string('text1')) else (string('text2'))` ?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing intrinsically wrong with your code, so it would be good to know how it is failing.

There are all sorts of mistakes you might be making, for example in misunderstanding what the exists() and nilled() functions do, but we really can't guess without seeing the symptoms, and a bit more context - e.g. what is $BookName actually bound to?

Answer (score 0):

`fn:exists()` wasn't working for me too. I had to change to `fn:string-length($BookName)>0` to figure out whether the variable has value or not. Works in case of `NULL` too.